# Outline or border for the spline series in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have created a graph using highcharts which has 6 series. 3 are column series and 3 are spline series.spline series will collide or go within the column chart so having a requirement to add outline to spline series to have better viewing. Trying to add a border color for the spline series but unable to do. But the same is possible in column chart.If anyone have tried this before for spline series kindly help.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderColor: '#303030'
        }
    },
```

this bordercolor is working for column but not in spline series

column chart
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-bordercolor/

would like to have border for the below series
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-datalabels-box/

Comment: Not a border but you could increase the `series.lineWidth' on just the spline series. The default is `2` maybe try `4`? You could also add a shadow on the spline series.

Comment: sorry for the late response, I need the different border color not the increase in thickness of the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature in Highcharts to set line border, but all is not lost.

You can achieve the effect you want, by adding new "fake" series basing on every line series, and set a couple of parameters.
Best place (in code) to do that would be the `chart.events.load` function, so there just find all series with `line` type:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load() {
       var series = this.series.filter(elem => elem.type === 'line')
    }
  }
}
```

Then, iterate on all the series found, and create new one so that it would have `color: [color_you_want]`, the same data and `marker.symbol`, increased `lineWidth` as well as `marker.radius`, won't be accessible by mouse and not visible in legend, just like below:

```
chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        var series = this.series.filter(elem => elem.type === 'line')
        series.forEach(series => {
          this.addSeries({
            data: series.userOptions.data,
            showInLegend: false,
            color: '#000',
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            zIndex: -9999,
            marker: {
              symbol: series.symbol,
              radius: series.options.marker.radius + 1
            },
            lineWidth: series.options.lineWidth + 2
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope, it helps you.

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yw2tb4nm/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker.symbol

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker.radius

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.showInLegend

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.enableMouseTracking

Comment: Thanks for the reply.got struck in another task.I have applied the same in my code but it is not working. I have made a jsfiddle for the same.https://jsfiddle.net/diasraphael88/op07nuhj/ .kindly suggest. Thanks

Comment: @Raphael, you do not have the `events` section in the correct spot. It should be under the `chart` section. You also need to set the new series' type to the same as the one you are bordering. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3brjh09v/

Comment: @Raphael additionally, you need to set the `zIndex` parameter on each spline series, to make it "above" the columns, and then add the same parameter to the new series you create, equal to `series.options.zIndex - 1`. Here is the example:  https://jsfiddle.net/937f2by4/ . If it helps you, please mark it as the answer. Also great thanks for @wergeld

Comment: odd double post - removed.